# Plasmashell desktops freeze after short time

Tags: linux, freeze, archlinux, kde-plasma

I am using KDE on Arch Linux and since I got a new Laptop, I cannot really use external Monitors. After some time (ranges from a few minutes to a few hours) my desktops start to freeze, that is the taskbar and the desktop icons and background just freeze and cannot be clicked anymore. The applications run fine and I can also change them by ALT+TAB or start new ones with ALT+F2 although the start menu doesn't come up if I press SUPER. All desktops freeze individually and not all at the same time, which can easily be seen as the clock in each monitors taskbar is stuck at a different time. I can't find a solution for my problem and I don't know how to start debugging it. I haven't noticed that problem when only using the laptop without a external monitor.

When this happens, my workaround is a `killall plasmashell && plasmashell` in a Konsole window, which then restarts the desktops/taskbars, making them usable again for a few minutes/hours.

When it happens while the screens are locked, I have to change the TTY, kill kscreenlocker_greet, which fortunately gets restarted automatically.

Can someone help me debug this?

I am running the following:

```
plasmashell 5.17.5
xorg-server 1.20.7-1
linux 5.4.15.arch1-1
```

- Laptop Dell Latitude 7480 (i5-7300U CPU @ 2.60GHz, no discrete graphics)
- Dock Dell WD15

I already tried to ask this in the [KDE Forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=164123), but sadly nobody was able to help me.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have this freezes, try to disable the compositor (ALT+SHIFT+F12) to see if it causes freezes.
Also you can try changing your compositor to Xrandr and see if with it you still have freezes.

Comment: I will try that, thank you. I have not used the above mentioned computer in weeks with the dock, so I don't know if I can still reproduce it.